# How can I get outlook to display background color

Tags: html

I am sending a html email. Outlook is stripping out my background color but gmail is not. How can I get outlook to display background color?

```
<tr style="text-align:center;background-color:lightgray;">
    <td style="font-size: 20px; font-family: arial, sans-serif, 'Century Gothic'; color: black; font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px;">
        My Text here
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: how is this information getting into outlook/gmail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your color is misspelled: `lightgrey` instead of `lightgray` would do the trick